# Fourier transform of fermionic operator product

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, fourier-transform, fermions

In the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01800 on page 11, there are 4 results (59),(60),(61),(62). These are basically Fourier transform of fermionic operators. **I am interested to know how the author comes up with three Kronecker delta functions in these results**. One of the results is as follows.

Equation (60):

$$\sum_{i\leq j}^{N/2}  c_{2i}^{\dagger}c_{2j}^{\dagger} = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k_{1},k_{2} =0}^{N-1} \frac{e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}2(k_1 +\frac{1}{2})}}{1-e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}2(k_1 +\frac{1}{2})}}(...) c_{k_1}^{\dagger}c_{k_2}^{\dagger}$$

where $$(...)=(\delta_{k_1+k_2+1,N}+\delta_{k_1+k_2+1,N/2}+\delta_{k_1+k_2+1,3N/2})$$

Shouldn't the summation be $\sum_{k_{1},k_{2} =0}^{N/2-1}$ instead of $\sum_{k_{1},k_{2} =0}^{N-1}$ ??